# Узнать, есть ли атрибут у вызывающего метода?

Tags: c#, атрибуты

Есть тестовое консольное приложение.

```
internal class Program
{
    [MyTest("TestDescription")]
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        TestSchmest ta = new TestSchmest();
        ta.GetSomeThingMethod();

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}

internal class TestSchmest
{
    public void GetSomeThingMethod([CallerMemberName] string methodName = "")
    {
        Console.WriteLine("\t - In hell we die!!!");
        WhoCalledMe();
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Method \"GetSomeThingMethod\" was called by {0}.", methodName);

        // methodName.GetAttribute ???
    }

    private void WhoCalledMe([CallerMemberName] string methodName = "")
    {
        Console.WriteLine("\t - For what?!");
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Method \"WhoCalledMe\" was called by {0}.", methodName);

        // methodName.GetAttribute ???
    }
}

public class MyTestAttribute : Attribute
{
    protected string Description;

    public MyTestAttribute(string description)
    {
        Description = description;
    }
}
```

Сначала вызывается метод `GetSomeThingMethod` класса `TestSchmest`, который в свою очередь вызывает метод `WhoCalledMe`. Можно ли как-то из методов класса `TestSchmest` узнать, указан ли атрибут у вызывающего их метода или нет.

Т.е. `ta.GetSomeThingMethod()` должен показать, что атрибут есть, а `WhoCalledMe()` что его нет.

Название класса, в котором вызываются методы (в данном случае `Program`) может быть неизвестно.

Comment: если название класса неизвестно - то никак, так как сами видите, что имя метода - обычная строка

Answer (score 5, accepted):

С помощью класса [`StackTrace`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stacktrace(v=vs.110).aspx) можно получить предыдущий кадр стека, относящийся к вызвавшему методу. Атрибут `CallerMemberName` при этом не требуется.

```
public void GetSomeThingMethod()
{
    string methodName = "";
    MyTestAttribute attribute = null;

    var st = new StackTrace();
    if (st.FrameCount > 1) {
        var prevFrame = st.GetFrame(1);  // получаем кадр стека для вызвавшего метода
        var caller = prevFrame.GetMethod(); // получаем сам вызвавший метод
        methodName = caller.Name;

        var attributes = caller.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(MyTestAttribute), false);
        if (attributes.Length > 0)
            attribute = (MyTestAttribute)attributes[0];
    }

    Console.WriteLine("\t - In hell we die!!!");
    WhoCalledMe();
    Console.WriteLine();
    Console.WriteLine("Method \"GetSomeThingMethod\" was called by {0}.", methodName);

    if (attribute != null)
        Console.WriteLine("Attribute is present.");
}
```

Результат:

```
Method "GetSomeThingMethod" was called by Main.
Attribute is present.
```

Answer (score 5):

Можно получить `MethodInfo` через класс `StackTrace`. Учтите, что это достаточно медленный способ, к тому же вам придется отключить inlining, чтобы JIT не вздумал встроить вызываемый / вызывающий метод в тело другого метода - иначе вы просто не увидите метод в stack trace:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

namespace ConsoleApplication58
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            AttributedMethod();
            NonAttributedMethod();
        }

        [MyTest("Some Description")]
        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.NoInlining)]
        static void AttributedMethod()
        {
            CallerDetectionSample();
        }

        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.NoInlining)]
        static void NonAttributedMethod()
        {
            CallerDetectionSample();
        }

        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.NoInlining)]
        public static void CallerDetectionSample()
        {
            // Get call stack
            StackTrace stackTrace = new StackTrace();

            // Get calling method name
            var attibutes = stackTrace.GetFrame(1).GetMethod().GetCustomAttributes(typeof(MyTestAttribute), true);

            var description = attibutes.Cast<MyTestAttribute>()
                .Select(a => a.Description)
                .FirstOrDefault() ?? "no attribute!";

            Console.WriteLine(description);
        }
    }

    public class MyTestAttribute : Attribute
    {
        public string Description { get; set; }

        public MyTestAttribute(string description)
        {
            Description = description;
        }
    }
}
```